# Color a tile while creating in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, tiles, color, st

I am trying to create a tile using PostGIS. Although I am able to create a tile but facing difficulty when coloring it. I want to color the tile means I want to color the geometry with different colors to create a tile and I followed [this link](https://research.geodan.nl/how-to-make-a-vectortile-basemap/) where they are adding the color as feature to the tile. In the same way I tried to add a green color (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Colors_in_SVG_graphics) using below query though the tile is generating but the color is not being applied, it shows a black color as default. What is the correct way of generating tile with colors?

Query:-

```
WITH bounds AS ( SELECT ST_Segmentize(ST_MakeEnvelope(x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max, 4326), seg_size) AS geom,
                    ST_Segmentize(ST_MakeEnvelope(x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max, 4326), seg_size)::box2d
                    AS b2d ), mvtgeom AS ( SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(t.geometry, bounds.b2d) AS geom,'#008000' as color
                                          FROM table_test t , bounds
                                          WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geometry, bounds.geom)) SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*) FROM mvtgeom
```

Comment: What tool are you using to display the tile ? Maybe you need to be sure that it properly recognize a 'color' field ?

Comment: MVT tile is just data. For rendering the data you must also define the rendering rules and styles according to Mapbox style specification https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/. You can use for example maputnik https://maputnik.github.io/editor/#0/0/0 and write a style that takes the polygon fill color from the color attribute of your MVT data.